# Creating a swap function for linked lists that takes two iterators as parameters?

Tags: c++, linked-list, swap

For this assignment, I have to use the standard implementation of a linked list [e.g. `class List`, `class Node`, `class Iterator`, all from the Big C++ textbook] and swap two elements of the List (I assume the elements are nodes), but my issue is the fact that we have to take two Iterators as parameters for the swap.

So, it looks like `void List::swap(Iterator i1, Iterator i2)`

My approach to the problem would be that I have to make temporary variables holding the data of the nodes I'm gonna swap and their positions, then erase one while inserting the other node's data in its position.

For example, by this I mean I would have two variables for `i2`: one holding its data [a string], and one holding its position [which we can find using the `get()` function in the `Iterator` class].

Then I would:

- erase `i1` [using the `List::erase(Iterator iter)` function]
- move the iterator to the position of `i1`
- then, insert a new node with `i2`'s data [using `List::insert(Iterator iter, string s)`]

Linked lists are still new and confusing to me, though, and I'm not sure if any of this would make sense to implement, and the fact that I have to use two Iterators as parameters is throwing me off.

Any help appreciated, thank you guys!

EDIT: Here are the implementations for List, Node and Iterator. The function definitions would take too much space.

**List**

```
class List
{
public:
    /**
       Constructs an empty list;
    */
    List();
    /**
       Appends an element to the list.
       @param data the value to append
    */
    void push_back(string data);
    /**
       Inserts an element into the list.
       @param iter the position before which to insert
       @param s the value to append
    */
    void insert(Iterator iter, string s);
    /**
       Removes an element from the list.
       @param iter the position to remove
       @return an iterator pointing to the element after the
       erased element
    */
    Iterator erase(Iterator iter);
    /**
       Gets the beginning position of the list.
       @return an iterator pointing to the beginning of the list
    */
    Iterator begin();
    /**
       Gets the past-the-end position of the list.
       @return an iterator pointing past the end of the list
    */
    Iterator end();
    void push_front(string s);
    void reverse();
    void swap(Iterator i1, Iterator i2);
private:
    Node* first;
    Node* last;
    friend class Iterator;
};
```

**Node**

```
class Node
{
public:
    /**
       Constructs a node with a given data value.
       @param s the data to store in this node
    */
    Node(string s);
private:
    string data;
    Node* previous;
    Node* next;
    friend class List;
    friend class Iterator;
};
```

**Iterator**

```
class Iterator
{
public:
    /**
       Constructs an iterator that does not point into any list.
    */
    Iterator();
    /**
       Looks up the value at a position.
       @return the value of the node to which the iterator points
    */
    string get() const;
    /**
       Advances the iterator to the next node.
    */
    void next();
    /**
       Moves the iterator to the previous node.
    */
    void previous();
    /**
       Compares two iterators
       @param b the iterator to compare with this iterator
       @return true if this iterator and b are equal
    */
    bool equals(Iterator b) const;
private:
    Node* position;
    List* container;
    friend class List;
};
```

Comment: Without seeing how the list and iterators are defined it is difficult to give an advice.

Comment: My recommendation is to not implement swap yourself, instead use [`std::iter_swap`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/iter_swap) (if your iterators fulfill the requirements) or [`std::swap`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/swap).

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude I am sure that std::iter_swap will not help.

Comment: Is there a way I can show how the list, node and iterator classes are implemented in a concise way? It's a lot of code, which is why I didn't include it.

Comment: @Zmu At least show how the iterator and node are defined.

Comment: All you need to modify is the `previous` and `next` members of the 2 nodes and their neighbours. Then possibly update `first` and/or `last` in `List`. The data itself should not be copied or moved. That is one of the benefits of using a linked list compared to an array.

Comment: You should either swap the nodes' data, leaving the nodes in the same place, *or* manipulate the nodes' pointers to swap their places, leaving the data untouched. You don't need to know the absolute positions in the list to move the nodes around, only the neighbours. Take out a piece of paper and draw a section of a list with boxes and arrows. Then figure out how you can redraw the arrows to swap places.

Comment: More specifically, draw three nodes. Call the one in the middle "node". Draw what happens when you modify `node->previous->next` and `node->next->previous`.

Comment: @molbdnilo I'm trying to make sense of them, would I still introduce a temporary Node* and then have each `node->previous->next` and `node->next->previous` point to the other node?

Comment: Considering the move-semantics of modern C++, do you really need to worry about moving the nodes around instead of just swapping the values stored in the nodes? Have you measured that this is a top-three bottleneck in your program? Don't over-engineer or over-complicate things that should be simple.

Comment: I finished the rest of the assignment easily, but this swap function has me stumped. The reason I don't know if I could just swap the values in the nodes is the fact that I have two iterators as arguments.

Comment: @Zmu You can figure it all out using pencil and paper and a bit of patience.

Comment: As an update @Someprogrammerdude, I just swapped the values and the code works. It's less satisfying but I realized the instructions don't explicitly say anywhere to swap the pointers, just "to swap two elements".